Ошибка в книге Бен Форта?
На странице 114 издания 2019 года написано что такое выражение <[Hh]([1-6])>.*?<\/[Hh][1-6]\1> с обратной ссылкой \1 найдёт строки с заголовками HTML. Это ошибка же ?

Надо читать книгу внимательно...... "Для обращения к обратным ссылкам в «строке-шаблоне» используется обратный слэш и присвоенный номер группе (\1)"   --- т.е. фактически 1 ссылается на группу в круглых скобках

Но в целом вопрос не ясен... ошибка где? что считаете ошибкой? и почему?

@АлексейШиманский, отлично вопрос ясен. Эта регулярка не найдёт то, что сказано.

@Qwertiy нет не ясен. ТС указывает на ошибку с \1, хотя технически проблема в другом месте.

@АлексейШиманский, нет причин под "это" понимать \1.

Сильное дело - одна ошибка. Был у меня когда-то классический справочник по высшей математике Гранино и Терезы Корнов. И пришёл ко мне приятель, попросил сделать курсовик по программированию, транспортная задача. Так вот, в этом справочнике на двух(!) страничках я нашёл 19 ошибок (в основном, опечаток) в описании транспортной задачи и её решения!

Да, это ошибка:
<[Hh]([1-6])>.*?<\/[Hh][1-6]\1>
                       ^^^^^----- выкинь это

